# Is there another way to do a regex without a String escaping all characters?

Tags: java, regex, readability

I have this line of code to remove some punctuation:

```
str.replaceAll("[\\-\\!\\?\\.\\,\\;\\:\\\"\\']", "");
```

I don't know if all the chars in this regex need to be escaped, but I escaped only for safety.

Is there some way to build a regex like this in a more clear way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `[`...`]` you don't need to escape the characters. `[.]` for instance wouldn't make sense anyway!

The exceptions to the rule are

- `]` since it would close the whole `[...]` expression prematurely.
- `^` if it is the first character, since `[^abc]` matches everything *except* `abc`.
- `-` unless it's the first/last character, since `[a-z]` matches all characters between `a` to `z`.

Thus, you could write

```
str.replaceAll("[-!?.,;:\"']", "")
```

To quote a string into a regular expression, you could also use `Pattern.quote` which escapes the characters in the string as necessary.

**Demo:**

```
String str = "abc-!?.,;:\"'def";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("[-!?.,;:\"']", "")); // prints abcdef
```

Comment: Without exceptions like the dot(.), parenthesis or brackets?

Comment: `-` has some meaning inside the brackets, but if it's at the beginning it's ok.

Comment: `.` doesn't need to be escaped... it wouldn't make sense to have `[.]`, would it?

Comment: No, but I have something like this in another regex: `str.replaceAll("[\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}]", "");`. In this case, all need to be escaped?

Comment: the dot is not an exception, neither parentheses, but if you have a right-square-bracket you want to match, you need to escape it.

Comment: It's worth noting that the reason he says to escape `^` if it's the only character is because `^` will negate inside a `[...]`. Conventional wisdom would be if you were to want to search for two particular characters, let's say `^` and `K`, you would do `[K^]` which would not require escape, instead of `[\^K]` which does require escape. It's not the fact that it's the only character, but simply that it only must be escaped when it's the first character, which is something you wouldn't do if there were other candidates for first character. Hope that's not too confusing! :-)

Comment: @Renato, no, only the `]` character.

Comment: You are all blowing my mind!!  What characters don't need to be escaped in `[]` ?  Are you telling me [.] is all I need to look for a period?  UGGGG.

Comment: Yes, `[.]` and `\.` will match the same thing :-)

Answer (score 3):

You might need to escape the double-quotes because you have the string in double-quotes; but as aioobe says, don't escape the rest. Put the `-` at the end of the group, however.

Comment: aioobe's updated answer is complete and this one is unnecessary, but since it got upvoted I'll leave it.

Comment: Well there's always the disciplined badge! :-)